# Asp.net core: action with raw string parameter

Tags: json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to write an action with a raw string parameter.

This string will be parsed dynamically as a json, so the keys in the json are not know at compile time.

I declared the method in this way:

```
[HttpPost("MyAction")]
public async Task<ActionResult<long>> MyAction([FromBody] string command)
{
    var cmd = MyCqrsCommand(command);
    return await Mediator.Send(cmd);
}
```

I call the method with swagger that shows a parameter as application/json

[image]

The result is this

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "|4e0e9c40-4036f8a9873ecac8.",
  "errors": {
    "$": [
      "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."
    ]
  }
}
```

I found two different solutions:

```
[HttpPost("MyAction")]
public async Task<ActionResult<long>> MyAction([FromBody] object command)
{ ... }
    
[HttpPost("MyAction")]
public async Task<ActionResult<long>> MyAction(string command)
{ ... }
```

Using object is not elegant but it works.
Using "string" in uri has some limitations, so I prefer the previous.

Which one is the best solution? And is there a way to insert the string in body declared as string and not object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which one is the best solution?

I perfer to use object parameter solution.

```
[HttpPost("MyAction")]
public async Task<ActionResult<long>> MyAction([FromBody] object command)
{ ... }
```

From the screenshot of your request we can see, you sent a **JSON object** `{ "key": "value" }` to your `MyAction` method. So you shouldn't declared your parameter as `string`.

> And is there a way to insert the
> string in body declared as string and not object?

If you expect to use "string" as input parameter, just send the content of value.

```
    [HttpPost("/MyAction")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<long>> MyAction([FromBody] string command)
```

[image]

Comment: You sent `"value"` which is not a valid json that usually is sent. Try to send the body with a valid json and you will see that your solution doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Use [JsonObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.json.jsonobject?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) as an input parameter instead of string and object.

Comment: OK, but this seems to require a specific json structure (from swagger): {
  "count": 0,
  "item": [
    null
  ],
  "jsonType": 0,
  "keys": [
    "string"
  ],
  "values": [
    [
      null
    ]
  ]
}; I prefer to have a free json to parse. Is it possible?